# Biblatex | list of bibliography doesn't print year

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, xetex, hebrew

I'm writing my final project report in LaTeX and I'm using XeTeX to compile my files, because all the report is in hebrew.

The problem is when I'm trying to print the bibliography (using BibLaTeX, with BibTeX as the backend), the whole bibliography list doesn't contain **the year field.**

[image: An example]

You can see for example that in the 1st reference, after the name Geoff in the first line, I get empty brackets instead of the brackets with the year of the reference inside them.

Compiler: XeTeX
Using also : BiDi, BibLaTeX, BibTeX
Running on Windows 10, using TeXStudio.

Note: The bibliography itself is in English (inside an LTR environment), but the whole report is in hebrew)

**document.tex**

```
    \documentclass{report}

% Add XeTeX Packages support for hebrew
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}

% Set BibTeX
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources}

% Fonts Support
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David}
\let\hebrewfonttt\ttfamily
\setmainfont{David}
\setmonofont{David}
\setsansfont{David}

\title{מסמך בדיקה}
\author{יוצר בדיקה}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \tableofcontents


    % Some Text
    \chapter{בדיקה ראשונה}

    שלום עולם, מה שלום כולם ?
    \nocite{*}


    % References' List
        \begin{LTR}
            \begin{sloppypar}
                \printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
            \end{sloppypar}
        \end{LTR}
\end{document}
```

**sources.bib**

```
@inproceedings{domingos2000mining,
  title={Mining high-speed data streams},
  author={Domingos, Pedro and Hulten, Geoff},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the sixth ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data mining},
  pages={71--80},
  year={2000},
  organization={ACM}
}

@article{garcia2010pattern,
    title={Pattern classification with missing data: a review},
    author={Garc{\'\i}a-Laencina, Pedro J and Sancho-G{\'o}mez, Jos{\'e}-Luis and Figueiras-Vidal, An{\'\i}bal R},
    journal={Neural Computing and Applications},
    volume={19},
    number={2},
    pages={263--282},
    year={2010},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: Welcome, we need to see a [minimal working eample](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) to reproduce that.

Comment: As Johannes says, without an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) we can resort only to guessing since there are too many variables we don't know about. Please consider adding an MWE to your question. It need not be so long that it reproduces the entire picture above, one or two entries will be more than enough.

Comment: @moewe I wonder if the bf *and*, *In* and *pages* has something to do with the problem.

Comment: @Johannes_B Mhhh, I saw that too. Maybe the language is still Hebrew in the bibliography. (That would explain the bold strings. But why would that make the year go away, if all other numbers seem to be printed just fine?)

Comment: Would you like to get a zip file containing the whole folder ? @moewe

Comment: @Johannes_B asking the same question above

Comment: Nah, a real minimal example is just a bit of text. No need to package that up. We don't need a bunch of entries, just one or two and how you set the bibliography up.

Comment: No, no, no. Please read the links we posted in our comments above. There you can find out about what we need.

Comment: @Johannes_B https://mega.nz/#!WAwnVbhA!erfj31OZ-szpY9i2VNKClp3cntWkHrNjRIf447qw-b4

Comment: @moewe Sent the link - minimum file as possible

Comment: If the file really is minimal you should be able to just copy the plaintext here, just edit your answer to include it. I'm very wary of zip files on the internet and am not very keen to download the file from some file sharing website.

Comment: @moewe edited the post as you requested

Comment: Brilliant! I will have a look.

Comment: You need `\addbibresources{sources.bib}`. You can only drop the file extension with `\bibliography` as far as I know. Is there any reason you cannot use Biber rather than BibTeX, by the way?

Comment: i think you can use biber, but it does give you the same results. also with sources.bib

Comment: It is not switching languages for the bibliography because it is still trying to use Hebrew. I can tell because I get nothing but boxes since the fonts I have for Hebrew, unlike David, do not include the Latin alphabet.

Comment: The issue @cfr is whether I can change the main language inside the document and change that afterwards.

Comment: Yes, but right now you don't change it afterwards - it isn't changed at all for the bibliography and that's a problem because the bibliography is written in English.

Comment: @moewe Do you know why I need a hack to restore the default definition of `\MakeUppercase` by any chance?

Comment: @cfr Sorry, not a clue. But when I played around with the example that confused me quite a bit as well.

Comment: There aren't many hebrew LaTeX users currently, and without nowledge of the script, development is very very slow. You can help other hebrew writers by providing *some* help to `biblatex` and `poluglossia`. It will be appreciated by other hebrew writers. :-)

Comment: @moewe It seems to be a bug in Polyglossia's Hebrew, according to Ulrike Fischer, who tracked it down in response to my question about this.

Comment: @cfr Good to know, thanks for following that up. The code in `biblatex` involving MakeUppercase looked innocent enough.

Comment: @moewe I didn't look. It was easy to reproduce without Biblatex, so I figured that regardless of Biblatex, there was a problem ;). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323831/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but I'm almost sure this is not the way to do it.

`\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont` need to specify the font for English because `\normalfontlatin` relies on the main document font being a Latin Script (Polyglossia manual, 6).

```
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
```

This may not matter so much if you are using a single font for English and Hebrew, of course.

You need to switch the language to English for the bibliography. This is pretty easy for the entries - just add `language=english` to Biblatex's options.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric,language=english,autolang=langname]{biblatex}
```

But you need to also ensure this is done for the title of the chapter, if you want that in English.

```
\printbibliography[title={\textenglish{Bibliography}}]
```

I also switched the language of the surrounding document to English using

```
\begin{english}
  ...
\end{english}
```

However, I had greatest trouble with the numeric labels in the bibliography, which are being taken by default from the Hebrew font. On my machine, this means they are just boxes. To ensure a consistent font for the bibliography, I added

```
\renewcommand\bibfont{\normalfontlatin}
```

which is why it matters a lot that this behaves as expected, of course.

I've also added the standard TeX ligatures to the Latin font setup since the bibliography uses things like ``, which won't work otherwise.

The final problem was that `\MakeUppercase` is then not defined when you switch the language to English. I assume this is a bug in something (Polyglossia?). Anyway, to work around this I created a new command to restore the default definition

```
\newcommand*\restoreuppercase{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{{% from base/latex.ltx
      \def\i{I}\def\j{J}%
      \def\reserved@a####1####2{\let####1####2\reserved@a}%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
      \protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{##1}}%
      \reserved@a
    }%
  }%
  \protected@edef\MakeUppercase##1{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
}
```

and added `\restoreuppercase` after starting the `english` environment and before executing `\printbibliography`.

The result:

[image: English bibliography in Hebrew document]

Complete code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{domingos2000mining,
  title={Mining high-speed data streams},
  author={Domingos, Pedro and Hulten, Geoff},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the sixth ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data mining},
  pages={71--80},
  year={2000},
  organization={ACM}
}

@article{garcia2010pattern,
    title={Pattern classification with missing data: a review},
    author={Garc{\'\i}a-Laencina, Pedro J and Sancho-G{\'o}mez, Jos{\'e}-Luis and Figueiras-Vidal, An{\'\i}bal R},
    journal={Neural Computing and Applications},
    volume={19},
    number={2},
    pages={263--282},
    year={2010},
    publisher={Springer}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
% % Add XeTeX Packages support for hebrew
\usepackage{polyglossia}% will load fontspec and bidi automatically
% % Set BibTeX
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric,language=english,autolang=langname]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% % Font Support
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\normalfontlatin}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\restoreuppercase{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{{% from base/latex.ltx
      \def\i{I}\def\j{J}%
      \def\reserved@a####1####2{\let####1####2\reserved@a}%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
      \protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{##1}}%
      \reserved@a
    }%
  }%
  \protected@edef\MakeUppercase##1{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
}
\makeatother
\title{מסמך בדיקה}
\author{יוצר בדיקה}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
% Some Text
\chapter{בדיקה ראשונה}
שלום עולם, מה שלום כולם ?
\nocite{*}

% References' List
\begin{english}
  \restoreuppercase
  \printbibliography[title={\textenglish{Bibliography}}]
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

I used Biber, but this may well work with BibTeX as the back-end, if you really don't want to use Biber.

Comment: You don't need to "Environment" the \printbibliography with "english" because the biblatex does that automatically.

Comment: @bar_boko I got the chapter title misaligned when I didn't use the environment, I think. That is, it was right aligned rather than left.