# How best to use \MakeUppercase in the english environment when the default language is Hebrew, Polyglossia is loaded and XeLaTeX is used?

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia, hebrew, english

The MNWE below fails to compile XeLaTeX. Compilation ends with an error because `\MakeUppercase` is undefined in the `english` environment.

Uncommenting the commented code permits compilation.

However, this surely should not be required in order to use a formatting command which is provided by the base LaTeX format.

How should the language/font setup be done so that Hebrew is the default document language, but `\MakeUppercase` works in the `english` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
% \makeatletter
% \newcommand*\restoreuppercase{%
%   \DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{{% from base/latex.ltx
%       \def\i{I}\def\j{J}%
%       \def\reserved@a####1####2{\let####1####2\reserved@a}%
%       \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
%       \protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{##1}}%
%       \reserved@a
%     }%
%   }%
%   \protected@edef\MakeUppercase##1{\MakeUppercase{##1}}%
% }
% \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{english}
%   \restoreuppercase
  \MakeUppercase{english}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in gloss-hebrew.ldf. In `\noextras@hebrew` it tries to restore `\MakeUppercase` without ensuring or checking that `\MakeUppercase` has been stored previously -- and as `\noextras@hebrew` is called the first time in a setup command at \begin{document} it fails.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{FreeMono}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}

\makeatletter
\def\noextras@hebrew{%
   \ifcsname @@MakeUppercase\endcsname
   \let\MakeUppercase\@@MakeUppercase%
   \fi
   }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{english}
  \MakeUppercase{english}
\end{english}

\MakeUppercase{ירושלים}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this is reported?

Comment: @cfr: I did it https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/152

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it with `letltxmacro`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{FreeMono}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\latex@MakeUppercase\MakeUppercase
\newcommand*\restore@uppercase{%
  \LetLtxMacro\MakeUppercase\latex@MakeUppercase
}
\appto\blockextras@english{\restore@uppercase}
\appto\inlineextras@english{\restore@uppercase}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{english}
  \MakeUppercase{english}
\end{english}

\MakeUppercase{ירושלים}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is considerably more elegant. But is this really supposed to be needed at all?